# How to implement a Layout between two entities

Tags: isis

I'd like to know how to implement a Layout between two entities so that it's possible to see in only one screen an entity that has a list of a second entity, and at the same time, this second entity has two lists of other entities.

```
Entidad: Autorizacion

@Property()
List<Ejecutante> ejecutantes;

--------
Entidad: Ejecuntate 

@Property()
Empresa empresa;

@Property()
List<Trabajador> trabajadores;

@Property()
List<Vehiculo> vehiculos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a view model, that's backed by the first entity (Autorizacion), and which then keeps track of the second level entity that's "selected" (Ejecuntate).

To select between different second level entities, you'll need an action.

It won't be the world's most elegant UI, but then you are bending the framework quite a bit here.

Comment: How do you do to implement that action you mentioned me in the last answer, that allows you to select between different second level entities?